# mysql odbc driver works fine on visual studio 2008 but not on visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010, odbc

Hey guys i got a problem which is doing my head in, and was hoping someone would be able to point me in t he right direction.

I have a c# application which i wrote using visual studio 2008 at the time i installed a mysql odbc 3.51 driver this app worked fine connection to a mysql db on my localhost and let me do what i needed to do.

i got a copy of visual studio 2010 from the microsoft dreamspark website installed it, opened the solution to the app i had written in 2008 made some changes ran it and it works totally fine.

Then i created a new application this time starting it in vs2010 created my odbc connection the same way as i did in the 2008 app but now i get an error saying:

"ERROR [IN002][Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified"

i then opened vs2008 and tried again to make a simple app to test my connection and it worked fine.

i can only quess that it is something to do with visual studio 2010.

any ideas would be most welcome :)

Vade

Comment: I'd recommend you just use Connector/Net rather than ODBC: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try re-installing the MySQL driver, there may be some Visual Studio tweaks it wants to make that would be present in your 2008 project but not in a fresh 2010 project if that was installed subsequently.