# "Data source name not found and no default driver specified" error

Tags: c#, asp.net, odbc, connection-string

I'm getting an error like `ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified` when publish the website. If I'm running the website from VisualStudio it's working fine, no issue. I had put the `connection string` in `web.config` file. The connection string is like
`<appSettings>
<add key="ConnectionStr" value="DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};SERVER=10.7.26.75;PORT=3306;DATABASE=XXXXXX;UID=XXXXX;PASSWORD=root123"/>
</appSettings>`

Please guide me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you publishing to a different computer/server? If so, it could be possible that the MySql ODBC Driver is not installed on the machine you are publishing to.

MySQL ODBC Driver:
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/

EDIT
Another thing to check. See [this article](http://bobobobo.wordpress.com/category/mysql/), and search for the text "Master genius John". He describes a similar error due to there being 32bit and 64bit versions of the driver. If you are running a 64bit OS, it's possible you've configured the DSN for one version and not the other.

Comment: No, I'm trying to publish from the same machine.That machine have already installed the `ODBC Connector`

Comment: Just to be clear, are publishing from your dev machine to another location on your dev machine?

Comment: Odd. Here's another question similar to yours with no answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831176/mysql-odbc-driver-works-fine-on-visual-studio-2008-but-not-on-visual-studio-2010

Comment: And another one here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181936/mysql-odbc-fails-in-c-net-project-but-not-runtime-compiled-code.

Comment: yes, it is resolved. i have installed the 64bit version of ODBC connector, because my machine is a 64bit machine. Actually previously i have installed 32 bit ODBC connector. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out. Of course if you like this answer you could always accept it. =]

Answer (score 7):

Had this same issue, the problem was I only had the 64 bit driver for my console application in C#, once I installed the 32 bit driver the program ran with no issues.

very weird.